# PushButtons on QGraphicsView aren't clickable

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qglwidget

I want to overlay a QGLWidget with clickable buttons.
I'm using a QGraphicsView and setting the viewport to a QGLWidget. Then I'm adding a layout to the QGraphicsView, and adding several QPushButtons to that.

 The Buttons display correctly, HOWEVER they are not clickable.

Here is my code:

```
    QGraphicsView* view = ui->gView;
    QGLWidget* gl = new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers));
    view->setViewport(gl);

    QPushButton* push = new QPushButton("Click me");
    QHBoxLayout* h = new QHBoxLayout;
    QPushButton* wo = new QPushButton("Wo");
    h->addWidget(wo);
    h->addWidget(push);
    view->setLayout(h);
```

Is there a simple way I can make the buttons get the clicks when the mouse is above them, and QGLWidget get the clicks otherwise?

Comment: Please provide additional information with steps to reproduce the issue. I just did copy and paste of your code into empty Qt Widget Application template and the buttons are clickable. I was able to receive their `clicked()` signal. How do you check that the buttons are not clickable?

Comment: Okay, I connected the clicked() signal to a slot and it does indeed call it. However, the button doesn't actually animate during the click. If I click on a button that is directly embedded in the centralWidget (rather than the GraphicsView), it turns blue during the click and white upon release. Whereas this button doesn't visually do anything upon click.

Comment: Do you observe such animation only with `QGLWidget` and `view->setViewport(gl);` or the animation always does not work with `QGraphicsView` even without changing default viewport? For me the animation always works as expected, however with `QGLWidget` the buttons have black border.

Comment: The issue only occurs for me with view->setViewPort(gl)

Comment: I think I resolved issue. I was using QT Creator to add the  QGraphicsView, and then was programmtically adding the buttons on top of it. This time, I added everything programmatically to the view, and the buttons behaved as expected. Thanks a lot for the help.